# WordPress generating invalid markup, How to remove it?

Tags: html, wordpress, validation, markup

Hi I am trying to get the categories associated with a post in it's meta section by using the following code:

```
<div>FILED AS: <span class="gf-post-meta-result"><?php the_category(' &bull; ') ?></span></div>
```

**WordPress is generating the markup as:**

```
<div>FILED AS: <span class="gf-post-meta-result"><a href="http://localhost/test/category/uncategorized/" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a></span></div>
```

**The issue:**

This part `rel="category tag"` generated by wordpress is making my code invalid. W3c Validator throws an error saying:

***Bad value category tag for attribute rel on element a: The string category is not a registered keyword or absolute URL. Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces.***

```
…w all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a></span></div>
```

**Any idea how to rectify this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just paste the following code in your `functions.php` file inside your theme folder

```
function remove_category_rel($output)
{
    $output = str_replace(' rel="category tag"', '', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('the_category', 'remove_category_rel');
```

Answer (score 5):

These two `rel` values are **not** invalid. The validator is not up to date.

- `tag` is [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-tag).
- `category` is [registered officially](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions).

So it's no problem to use these values. The validator will probably catch up in the future.