# Invalid Wordpress rel='category' markup, why is it invalid?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, w3c-validation

Wordpress generates category links with a `rel="category"` attribute. When I run my site through w3c.org's validator, it tells me that this is invalid, and that I can register link types on the Microformats wiki (http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions). However,

Is this a problem with the validator, or am I doing something incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14114465/1591669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rel` value "`category`" is **not** invalid. Instead, the validator is not up to date.

`category` is [registered officially](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) in the microformats.org wiki page.

So it's no problem to use this value. The validator will probably catch up in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things for me.